# Issue displaying data from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I got an issue to display my data that I fetch from an API, I don't really what is going wrong here...

I tried to use the map() function to access the data but it's not working as expected as well

```
import React from "react";
import axios from 'axios';

const options = {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
            Authorization: 'API_KEY'
      }
};

export default class List extends React.Component {
    state = {
        locations: []
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('https://api.foursquare.com/v3/places/search?query=gallery%20&ll=48.85%2C2.35&radius=10000&categories=10004&sort=DISTANCE', options)
            .then(res => {
                const locations = res.data;
                console.log(locations.results)
                return this.setState({ locations });
            })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
               
            <ul>
               <div>{this.state.locations.results}</div>
            </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I got these two errors showing up

1: Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {fsq_id, categories, chains, distance, geocodes, location, name, related_places}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

2: Unhandled Promise Rejection: Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {fsq_id, categories, chains, distance, geocodes, location, name, related_places}). If you meant to render a collection of children...

This is the object that I got back in the log:

[Log File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blKpD.png)

Any leads would be so much helpful, thank you!! :)

Comment: Perhaps post an example of the object you get?

Comment: pls. do NOT use screenshots (and images) for example data. Use something that can be copied over to the answer - easily. Help SO members, so they can help you!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the screenshot, you get back an array. React/JSX doesn't just put the array out, you need to iterate over it. Here's a snippet with functional component & a custom hook:

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React

const useFetchData = () => {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState([])
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(() => true)
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => setResponse(() => json))
      .finally(setLoading(() => false))
  })
  
  return { response, loading }
}

const App = () => {
  const { response, loading } = useFetchData()
  return (
    <div>
      {
        response.length && !loading
        ? response.map(({ id, name, username }) => {
          return (
            <div key={id}>{id} - {name} - {username}</div>
          )
        })
        : "Loading users..."
      }
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Although you used a class component in your example and this is a functional component in my snippet, the basic idea is the same: if you want to display an array of items in JSX, then you need to iterate over them with an iterator function that actually returns a JSX element.